# javascript: different behaviour for the same script

Tags: javascript, document.write

I  have some questions about a javascript behaviour (I am learning now javascript from w3schools) and I've seen two examples with a simple code,but I don't understand why the code is behaving different:
First example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script>
document.write(5 + 6);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Second example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Why in the second example all document content is replaced with "11" and in the first example "11" as appended to the document? Is there a difference when the script is executed?

Ps: I know that this is not the right place to ask this, but if you know a better book or tutorial to learn javascript, please put it in a comment ( I am a c# backend developer and ex android developer).

Comment: In the first example document is being built, in the second one it's built. Btw, it's really very rare cases when you should use `document.write` ever.

Comment: Since you have good background, i guess this could be a better place to learn JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript... Also, this guy is extraordinary teacher: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts  (this course is good for absolute beginners, but also, covers some very advanced (and strange) concepts of javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because in the 1st example, the browser **would not** invoke the `document.open` automatically, but the 2nd one did.

Here is the words from mdn document.write

> If the document.write() call is embedded directly in the HTML code,
>   then it will not call document.open().

Basically `document.open` just clear all the content in your document.

Check these documents about `document.write` and `document.open`
[mdn document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#Notes)
[mdn document.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open)

Thank you buddy! Nice question! Didn't notice this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use document.write once the document has completed loading. If you do, the browser will open a new document that replaces the current.

Use the innerHTML property to put HTML code inside an element:

```
 <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
 <p>My first paragraph.</p>
 <span id='r'></span>
 <button id="add"">Try it</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick = add;
function add(){
   document.getElementById("r").innerHTML=5+6;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/ktx0rmuf/

Comment: I found these examples on w3school but they didn't explained why this script works different and I was curious

Comment: The first one append to the same document on loading and the second one override on the document on user event